# Detect badly formatted Accept-Language HTTP header

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-3.5

I want to parse the `Accept-Language` header. All answers that I find deal with parsing the string but do not handle the case of a badly formatted input.

For example what if the user is sending this header `Accept-Language: en,es;q=0.5;*;q=0.5` which is badly formatted because of the second `;`. Is there any package that can offer easy parsing and appropriate exception raising?

Comment: This certainly depends on what language do you use and what do you mean by "Parse" language. Do you just want to get tokens such as `en` and `es`? What do you want to do with `q=0.5`? Do you want to ignore it or throw an error?

Comment: In the case of a badly formatted header I want to make the user aware, but to detect a badly formatted header I prefer to not hardcode rules myself

Comment: Then the question is what does the "good" header looks like?
Someone will have to define the rules for a properly formatted header and you could use that rule to parse the header. If at some point the header doesn't correspond to the rule, then it's badly formatted. `q=0.5` represents a weight and it should always appear after the language mnemonic. You could use that as a basic rule to follow

Comment: I thought that the language should be followed by a `;` when there is explicit weight defined like that `en;q=0.4` and that the second language should be placed after a comma like that `en;q=0.4, de;q=0.1`, If you notice in the provided example there is a `;` before the asterisk, which I think is wrong. am I not correct on that? If I am then I think it's quite clear what I am looking for.

Comment: Well, you can have a language range followed by `;` and then the weight. 
You can see the definition here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4
`Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":" 1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )` and  then `language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )`

Comment: yes but you can't have a quality range followed by a `;`, right? it's quite clear what I am asking I think, I don't see where the confusion stems from

Answer (score 1):

First you should start by understanding the proper format of the `Accept-Language` header: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4

You can see the definition of the `Accept-Language` header field is:

```
Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":"
                  1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )
       language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
```

An example of the properly formatted header is: `Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`. You can see that each comma `,` separates the language tuples, where each language tuple is `language-range` and `quality weight` (optional).

Now that you know how is the `Accept-Language` header defined, the only problem is how to parse it.

You can implement this in many ways depending on the language, but I will write a pseudo-code:

```
function parseAcceptLanguageHeader(headerValue):
    parsedLanguages = []
    languageStrings = headerValue.split(",")
    foreach languageStrings as S do
        parsedLanguages.add(parse(S))
    return parsedLanguages


// Here we define parse(S)
function parse(S): // expecting format of S to be like: 'language-range [";q=<number>"]'
    vals = S.trim().split(";") // remove leading and trailing spaces and split by ;
    if vals.length == 1: // means 'q=qvalue' part is missing
      return vals[0].trim(), 1.0 // default q is 1.0; you can additionally verify that vals[0] is one of the languages that you support
    else if vals.length == 2:
      return vals[0].trim(), parseQuality(vals[1])
    else raise an error ("Expected two tokens but, got: " + S)


// Implement parse quality
function parseQuality(S):
  // We expect to see 'q=<number>'
  vals = q.split("=")
  if (vals.length != 2):
    raise an error ("Expected exactly two tokens for quality, but got: " + S)
  else if (vals[0] != 'q'):
    raise an error ("Expected quality (q) but got: " + S)
  else 
    return parseInt(vals[1].trim()) // This can also throw an error, but I am not going to write implementation for that function
```

Note that depending on the language dealing with errors is different.

Comment: Sorry but the answer does not address my question at all. First I don't see why you assume that I wasn't aware of the proper format since my question does not indicate likewise and second all I am asking is if there is a package that can take care of the parsing of the header and in case it detects a badly formatted header it will let me know, what I want to avoid is implement the detection myself. Since as you also mentioned the format of a header is properly specified in the protocol there could be some kind of protocol validator that could do that job

Comment: Ok, I see. I suppose you should be more explicit to avoid the confusion. Are you looking for a library in the specific language or that is not important to you?

Comment: yes, I am looking for a python package, thnx for taking the time

Comment: Sorry I can't help with that. I'm not a python expert. I've tried searching for some but the only two that I've found are: https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html and https://pypi.python.org/pypi/http-parser, however I don't think they will do what you are asking for.